# Custom Master Page - CEWP/JQuery Broken

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am using a script that adds scollbars to a doc library webpart which works fine on sites using the "default.master" system master page, but once I attempt to use my custom master page it breaks the jquery and the scrollbars do not appear.

Any idea on what I can look at in my custom master page to fix this? I am using a CEWP and not directly including the jquery inside my master page.

scollbar script (just in case)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

<!--

.DataGridFixedHeader { position: relative; top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);}

-->

</style>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var $table = $("TABLE[ID^='onetidDoclibViewTbl0']", 

"#MSO_ContentTable");



<!--WRAP TABLE IN SCROLL PANE-->

$table.wrap("<DIV style='OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 250px'></DIV>");

<!--FROZEN HEADER ROW-->

$("TR.ms-viewheadertr:first", $table).addClass("DataGridFixedHeader");

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the browser console to see if the jquery is being correctly loaded? Or if there is another script error? This script seems to be fine but if you have a script error on the page before this it will never be loaded.